# My hairless cat is cold and shivering

Tags: cats, health

I bought a hairless cat. It's winter though and its really cold outside. It's also cold inside as we don't have thermostat.

I notice that the cat is often shivering. I try to put blanket on it but it needs to walk sometimes.

Are there leg warmers or something just for cats?

Comment: It is not possible to give an answer as it would mean brand advertising. However your cat is definitely suffering. The idea of @trondhansen is good, but there are definitely lots and lots of cat specific warm clothes on e-commerce sites which you should definitely try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possible warming solutions, including putting a coat or sweater on your cat (purchased or homemade), an electric warming bed or heating pad (use the type intended for humans with caution-- they may get too hot and burn your cat), or an enclosed hideaway like a box, enclosed bed or cat house with warm blankets within.  It should have a smallish opening and be not much bigger than the kitty to maximize conservation of body heat.

You can also possibly improve the indoor comfort by reducing drafts-- make sure that windows and doors are well sealed, or use any kind of calking, draft stoppers, or heavy window drape that makes sense for your home.

Also be sure to place as many as possible of your cat's important resources (like litter box, resting places, water bowl, scratching surface) in the warmest and least drafty parts of the house.